# Error to call date picker dialog using fab

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am new in programming, i got stuck on android feature.
I have a float action button and I am trying to use it for opening a date picker dialog, but Im getting an exception which says:

"Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.herman.homeSchedule/com.herman.homeSchedule.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.fab_new_schedule) must not be null"

any idea how to fix it???

here is my float action button xml

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_new_schedule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

here is my code in onCreate

```
val fab : View = findViewById(R.id.fab_new_schedule)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("Button", "FAB clicked")
            val now = Calendar.getInstance()
            val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
                this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this, "year : " + year
                                + "\n Month : " + month
                                + "\n Date: " + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                },
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            )
            datePicker.show()
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `FloatingActionButton` was not found in your activities layout.

You need to add the `FloatingActionButton` to the `activity_main` layout (or how you called it) and then call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in MainActivity's onCreate.

If you did this and it still doesn't work, can you please provide the full layout which includes the FAB?

Comment: Thank you very much @abarth911, yes it worked with you solution.. actually my main_activity is a login screen, after the login screen, I have another screen containing this float button, I have a recycler view along to the button, but classes of this recycler view are in java class, i wanna use this button from this recycler view screen. thanks

Comment: I figured out, it was a silly mistake, my code was simply out the onCreate method. thank you guys for the help anyway.